# c# how to take data_type as input in "foreach" clause

Tags: c#

I want a code can automatically detect data type and do the foreach loop.
For example print element in an array one by one. But we don't know the type of this array in advance. I got a solution that use any_array.GetType().ToString() to get string of the data type.
but this is too stupid.

Is there any more elegant way to do that?

```
using System;

public class basic_data_structure
{
    public static void example01()
    {
        int[] int_array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // type = System.Int32[]
        float[] float_array = new float[] { 1F, 2F, 3F, 4F, 5F }; // type = System.Single[]
        string[] string_array = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" }; // type = System.String[]

        print_any_array01(int_array);
        print_any_array01(float_array);
        print_any_array01(string_array);
    }

    public static void print_any_array01(Array any_array)
    {
        int count = 0;
        string array_type = any_array.GetType().ToString();

        if (array_type == "System.Int32[]")
        {
            foreach (int element in any_array)
            {
                count += 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Element #{0}: {1}", count, element);
            }
        }
        else if (array_type == "System.Single[]")
        {
            foreach (float element in any_array)
            {
                count += 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Element #{0}: {1}", count, element);
            }
        }
        else if (array_type == "System.String[]")
        {
            foreach (string element in any_array)
            {
                count += 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Element #{0}: {1}", count, element);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR unknown data type array!!!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Steve and Dmitry's solution both works. But any one can give me a solution can return the data type of the array?

Comment: In my solution data type of the array would be `typeof(T)`. And in both solutions it could be reached via `element.GetType()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use generics:

```
public static void print_any_array01<T>(T[] any_array)
{
    int count = 0;

    foreach (T element in any_array)
    {
        count += 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Element #{0}: {1}", count, element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [var keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

```
public static void print_any_array01(Array any_array)
{
    foreach (var element in any_array)
    {
        count += 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Element #{0}: {1}", count, element);
    }
}
```

And if you really want to know what type is the array passed you could add

```
    if(any_array is int[])
        Console.WriteLine("Integer array");
    else if(any_array is float[])
        Console.WriteLine("float array");
    else if(any_array is string[])
        Console.WriteLine("string array");
```

Not a big gain however....

Comment: but in Dmitry's answer it also doesn't tell me the data type of the array.

Comment: @MacSanhe well added also a bit to discover the array type with a different approach

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can probably just use `Object`. I'd also be tempted to ask for IEnumerable instead of an array. This will allow you to also accept Lists and other sequences to the function, in addition to the array:

```
public static void PrintSequence(IEnumerable any_array)
{
    int count = 0;

    foreach (Object element in any_array)
    {
        count += 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Element #{0}: {1}", count, element);
    }
}
```

In this case, the `WriteLine()` function will end up calling `.ToString()` on anything passed in. If there's not an existing overload, you may end up seeing the name of the type, instead of the value. You can improve on this with Generics and Delegates, like so:

```
public static void PrintSequence<T>(IEnumerable<T> any_array)
{
    PrintSequence(any_array, null);
}

public static void PrintSequence<T>(IEnumerable<T> any_array, Func<T, string> toString)
{
    if (toString == null) toString = (x) => x.ToString();

    int count = 0;

    foreach (T element in any_array)
    {
        count += 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Element #{0}: {1}", count, toString(element));
    }
}
```

And you can call that exactly the same way you call your existing method, or you can call it with instructions on how to produce a string from the desired object type.

Note that none of these show the type of your original array. However, your sample code didn't really care about the type of the array, either.

Comment: @MacSanhe Please define "doesn't work". What error do you get? I had to type that directly into the Answer window, without an IDE, so it may just be a trivial error.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to cast it to the correct type if you don't want to use generics. This follows the structure of your code, but just casts the array instead of accessing the type directly.

```
using System;

public class basic_data_structure
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] int_array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // type = System.Int32[]
        float[] float_array = new float[] { 1F, 2F, 3F, 4F, 5F }; // type = System.Single[]
        string[] string_array = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" }; // type = System.String[]

        print_any_array01(int_array);
        print_any_array01(float_array);
        print_any_array01(string_array);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void print_any_array01(Array any_array)
    {
        int count = 0;

        int[] int_array = any_array as int[];
        float[] float_array = any_array as float[];
        string[] string_array = any_array as string[];

        if (int_array != null)
        {
            foreach (int element in int_array)
            {
                count += 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Element #{0}: {1}", count, element);
            }
        }
        else if (float_array  != null)
        {
            foreach (float element in any_array)
            {
                count += 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Element #{0}: {1}", count, element);
            }
        }
        else if (string_array != null)
        {
            foreach (string element in any_array)
            {
                count += 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Element #{0}: {1}", count, element);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR unknown data type array!!!");
        }
    }
}
```